# File Transfer Compression on Android

Tags: android, algorithm, compression, media

I am currently working on a File transfer app on android. I am building this for the transfer of files upto 2GB. I mainly transfer media files and very little text files.

Since my major transfer is of media (like videos, images, audio etc). I want to know whether compression while file transfer will help me speed up my file transfer process..?

This question arises as most images are in JPEG format which is already compressed. I am not very sure about videos. So, what I am looking for is a compression algorithm that is mostly lossless(ideal or 90% lossy), so that I can decompress the file as it is (or without any perceivable quality difference) on the other side.

1. What are the algorithms that will help me ?
2. Will the time taken while compression and transferring compressed file be less than the time taken for transferring un-compressed file?
3. If there do exist such algorithm, can you point to to some implementations or any existing library implementing them.

Thanks!

Comment: Don´t bother. Most file formats for images/audio/video are already heavily compressed. An encoding of (especially) videos takes long, especially on your Android device

Comment: @deviantfan Yeah I am currently not focussing on this part. But will be nice if I get to know some interesting algorithm! ;)

Comment: Algorithm? I think your underestimating this by magnitudes. Coding a single codec is a big project even alone, but understanding why and how the algo works without any previous knowledge... well, no idea, but "long" (tm). To start with, many modern algos are patented in some countries. ... There are libs to encode/decode media stuff without knowing the interals, but you won´t gain anythin with reencoding already heavily compressed audio/video data to save bandwith. It gets much slower, very likely.